# Is it possible to export and import an entire JS file without adding Export and Import to every function, etc?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to include a whole file, instead of having to import every individual function, etc, into my JS? Some of what I've been reading; I'm not sure what I'm missing:

- [Exports at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)
- [[es6] import, export, default cheatsheet](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)

Comment: in your file, write everything inside a class/object and export it.

Comment: `import * from ...`…?!

Comment: @deceze That's not JS :-)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Bergi Why would you want to modularize your code without having to write 'export' on every single block that you want to access later?

Comment: @MichaelMoreno Why would you call that modularisation if you're not using module exports? Writing `export` on the things you want to access elsewhere (and only on those) is a good thing, as it signals that this function is part of the public interface of the module.

Comment: @Bergi The desire is to achieve a type of modularization similar to how Sass works, where you can load in the contents of entire files into one main file, rather than specific data blocks inside those files.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno That only works for CSS where everything lives in a global namespace. ES6 modules fortunately moved away from global scoping in scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shown in the second part of **1. Name exports** of `[es6] import, export, default cheatsheet`

```
import * as mymodule from './modulename';

mymodule.exportedMember1...
```

Comment: Better `mymodule` than `myclass`. A module namespace object never behaves like a `class`.

Comment: @Bergi so `import * as modulename from './modulename';`?

Comment: So what would the export JS file look like? Care to elaborate some on that? Would I need to clarify anything or not, since it'd be importing the whole file as a module?

Comment: @code4ever You still need to `export` every single value that you want to export. There's no way around that. And it's a good thing.